# How to nest a dataframe in R based on columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, nested

I am trying to nest a dataframe (e.g. iris), so that the **columnames** and **class** (e.g. numeric, factor etc.) are in separate columns and rows and the **data** are in nested list. Needs to be with dplyr.

The result should look like this:

[image: Image of desired result]

Thanks a lot for your help and

best regards
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write this directly in a single line:

```
tibble(class = sapply(iris, class), column = names(iris), nested = as.list(iris))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   class   column       nested      
#>   <chr>   <chr>        <named list>
#> 1 numeric Sepal.Length <dbl [150]> 
#> 2 numeric Sepal.Width  <dbl [150]> 
#> 3 numeric Petal.Length <dbl [150]> 
#> 4 numeric Petal.Width  <dbl [150]> 
#> 5 factor  Species      <fct [150]>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
out <- data.frame(class = sapply(iris, class), 
                  column_name = names(iris), row.names = NULL)
out$nested <- as.list(iris)
View(out)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We could create a list with `data.frame` call using `I`

```
data.frame(class = sapply(iris, class), 
        column_name = names(iris), nested = I(as.list(iris)))
```